# ¿Cómo puedo usar un modal como alert?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

tengo un problema y es que quiero hacer un login en bootstrap, y al momento de presionar el botón este abra un archivo javascript para comparar los campos del login y de ahí si es correcto muestre un modal y si es incorrecto muestre otro modal.

Este es mi js

```js
function validar(form){
        
    if(form.usuario.value != "Admin") {
        
    form.usuario.focus();return false;
    }
    if(form.password.value != "Admin123") {
    
        form.password.focus();return false;
    }
    return true;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" id="cuerpo">
  <div class="card card-outline-secondary">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="mb-0">Punto de Acceso</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form" role="form" autocomplete="off" id="loginForm" novalidate="" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validar(this);">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="uname1">Usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" id="uname1" required="">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" required="" autocomplete="new-password">

                </div>
                <div class="form-check small">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"> <span>Recordar en este equipo</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btnLogin">Entrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--/card-body-->
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Usuario o contraseña Incorrecta.
                     </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias hacer algo como esto:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <form class="form-signin">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Login</h1>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuario</label>
  <input type="text" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="usuario" required autofocus>
  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Clave</label>
  <input type="password" id="clave" class="form-control" placeholder="clave" required>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onclick="validarSesion();">Iniciar Sesión</button>
</form>


<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalMensaje">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title badge badge-success">MENSAJE</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="mensaje"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">SALIR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
function validarSesion(){
 usuario = 'root';
  clave = '123456';
  
  var usuarioIngresado = $("#usuario").val();
  var claveIngresado = $("#clave").val();
  if((usuario == usuarioIngresado) && (clave == claveIngresado )){
   MENSAJE = "ACCESO CORRECTO ..!!";
       $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
    $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
  }else{
   MENSAJE = "ACCESO INCORRECTO ..!!";
   $("#mensaje").html(MENSAJE);
   $("#modalMensaje").modal('show');
  }
}//end function validarSesion
</script>
```

Si te fijas uso una funcion **validarSesion** la misma mediante jquery y con el ID obtengo el usuario y clave ingresados, luego los comparo con unas variables previamente establecidades **usuario** y **clave** en caso de que coincidan muestro una ventana modal con un mensaje, caso constrario cun otro distinto.
Hice con la misma modal para optimizar dado que sera como alerta como lo mencionas. pero puedes adaptarla a tus necesidades, espero te sirva y guie..!!